# Cannot start Go server on localhost

Tags: macos, go, xcode8

Today, i encountered a very strange problem concerning a local server in Go on MAC OS X 10.12.2. Suddenly, after a successful build, i cannot start my application. Every time i get a "Killed 9" message.

This problem could be caused by two dependencies:

1. `github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher`
2. `github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host`

Without them the application can start, but I need them.

I  have been using those two dependencies for two months and I haven't had any problems with them. The problem happened suddenly after a successful build. I cloned the whole repository into two environments with Mac OS X 10.12.2 and Windows 8 and I didn't get any problems. The applications started on both machines.

Probably due to constant application checks and dozens of local servers created, MAC OS blocks some processes, but I couldn't find out where the problem is.

Comment: Can you determine which of those packages is specifically causing the issue? I would wager that `github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host` is doing something unsupported

Comment: Please share a code that produces an error.

Comment: Of the two dependencies you mentioned, only `gopsutil` explicitly uses [methods that send signals](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/tree/d371ba1293cb48fedc6850526ea48b3846c54f2c/process). Probably safe to start focusing on that library first.

Comment: Yes, actually method Pids() in the process_darwin.go causes the problem. Unfortunately, even if I avoid using gopsutil dependency, i still got the problem with go-sqlcipher

Comment: Ok, looks like `Pids()` really just ends up calling the bash command `ps -ax -o pid`. I think i need to see the traceback of this error and what you saw with `sqlcipher` to be any more help.

Comment: See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some issue with the Sierra command line tools that were released today as part of xcode 8.3. Totally hosed my go project with immediate Killed: 9 upon running it. I had to revert back to command line tools from 8.2

Comment: You are right! Actually, i downloaded previous version of the XCode and input command:  `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_821.app/Contents/Developer`. Now everything works fine.